# jQuery DataTable width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have a table generated by me using javascript this table have a filter button that reloads the table according to my filter and then, DataTable it:

```
//here i declare the dataTable and clear it.
Table = $('#pattern-style-a').dataTable();
Table.fnClearTable();

//here is a lot of functions that generates a html table with data contents.
<Javascript code that generates the html table with its data>

//here i transform my table into a dataTable(**the problem**)
$('#pattern-style-a').dataTable({
  "bDestroy": true,
  "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
  "bSort": true,
  "aaSorting": [[ 4, "asc" ]]
});
```

**My problem is**: When i transform my table into a dataTable it works but reduces 2px from the whole table every time that i do it.

So everytime that i execute these codes my table reduces 2px, it continues happening infinitely and i really dont know why and where are these -2px thing.

Does someone know about this weird width reduce when clearing and re-transforming a table into a datatable ?

Comment: Is a static pixel dimension being applied to it by the script? This along with a border could explain where something is calculating dimensions incorrectly.

Comment: I have a border in my table, i cant have one?